# How do I post a code example if I don't know which file the problem is in?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

I'm having a problem with a C++ class field that isn't keeping its value, but there's a few different files, and I'm not sure in which file the problem lies. What's the best way to deal with this situation? Should I just post every file? (there's 5 of them, I think, including header files)

Comment: By using a debugger.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 14):

It’s not always particularly easy to do, but we expect you to try to strip down your code to the minimal amount necessary to demonstrate the problem, in a [short, self-contained, compilable example](http://www.sscce.org/).

How you get to that point is up to you: you might try stripping things out of your code until the problem goes away, and then backing up to where it still fails, and repeating until anything further you remove makes the problem go away.  (There are tools to automate this, like [Delta](http://delta.tigris.org/), though it requires some configuration.)  Or maybe you could go the other way around, starting from a blank slate again and moving in your code piece-by-piece, to see what component brings the error to light.

But however you do it, we do expect it to be done; if you do end up posting five files worth of code, I really doubt it’ll get read as thoroughly as you’d like, and your question would probably also get downvotes.  Reducing the problem and explaining what you think the problem might be and what you’ve tried to work around it has significantly better chances at being well-received.

You may even discover what the problem was while reducing it; if so and the solution is relevant to others, you can proceed to write the question as if you hadn’t solved it and then tick the “answer your own question” box and write an answer.

Comment: +1, especially *You may even discover what the problem was while reducing it*. How awesome wouldn't it be if everyone did that before asking questions?

Comment: @ivarni - yeah.  It seems that SO is infested by pople who can write lines of code and get them to compile/link, but have the debugging skills of a West Ham supporter after 10 pints of Stella.